# Error parsing json with unexpected properties - how to relax parsing rules?

Tags: jackson, dropwizard

I have an API hosted/written in DropWizard. It consumes JSON and works well

```
@POST
public void somePost(SomeObject object)
```

Where `SomeObject` is a pojo. Jackson deserialises JSON into the object without a problem.

To future proof the "calling code" that uses this API I started to add some properties that are not yet in `SomeObject`. However (presumably Jackson) now throws an "error parsing json" error.

I would like to relax the rules a bit so that Jackson is a bit more tolerant about fields that it doesn't recognise in the incoming JSON (GSON does that by default). I tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties` class level annotation but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you tried @JsonIgnoreProperties. Have you tried it like this?

> @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Tested above one and it should work.

Comment: Ah ok no I just tried without the annotation contructor. That looks like the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just globally allow any and all unknown properties by disabling `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`. It may be dangerous in just ignoring everything that does not map, but for "Open Content" style usage it works great.